# dir() not able to recognize external path

Tags: vba

I am trying to get dir() to recognize a path on an external drive, however for some reason I can't get it to work. Is the function not meant to work on external drives?

```
Public Sub Test()
    If Dir("D:\Folder\") = "" Then
        Debug.Print "External drive not found."
    Else
        Debug.Print "External drive found."
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `can't get it to work` - that is an unhelpful description of the problem. What does it do and how is it different from your expectations?

Comment: @GSerg: My code above returns "External drive not found." My expectations were to get "External drive found." The code works fine when looking up paths on my C: drive.

Comment: Do you indeed have ``D:\Folder\``? Do you provide the final slash?

Comment: Yes, the folder exists. I included the final slash. I have checked the comparison, created a identical path on the C drive (C:\Folder\) which worked fine.

Comment: If you need to check a folder existence, please try `If Dir("D:\Folder\", vbDirectory) = "" Then`

Comment: @FaneDuru That worked, thanks! How come dir() works without vbDirectory for local drives like C:?

Comment: Well, ` Dir("D:\Folder\")` does not return a folder path. It returns the first file name only **if there is at least a file inside the respective folder**. `Dir("D:\Folder\", vbDirectory)` specifically check if the respective folder exists. Even if it is empty... It returns a dot (`.`)... In fact, it can find (in a loop) all files and sub folders from the respective folder.